# Is there a way to verify to probe that read() method made a perfect read on a file?

Tags: c++, fstream

im looking to verify that read made a perfect read on a file, is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

Check for the state flags:

```
eofbit
failbit
badbit
```

Or check if it throws `ios_base::failure` exception

Comment: when eofbit is set, `gcount()` can also be necessary information to understand what `read()` achieved

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "perfect read", but `failbit` will be set if
the stream was unable to read the requested number of characters; in
other words, if you ask for 20 bytes, and only 19 are available, the
read is deemed to have failed.

The usual way of testing for failure is simply by treating the stream as
a boolean, e.g.:

```
if ( input ) //  succeeded
```

or

```
if ( ! input ) //  failed
```

(This also takes `badbit` into consideration, which will be set if there
is an actual I/O problem when reading.)

In the case of `istream::read`, you may also want to check
`istream::gcount` in case of failure; `istream::gcount` returns the
number of characters read by the last unformatted read, even in case of
failure.  Thus, when reading raw data, it's not unusually to use
something like:

```
while ( input.read(...) || input.gcount() != 0 ) {
    //  process input.gcount() characters...
}
```

This is slightly different from the usual idiom, which stops as soon as
the input fails.